# Excel Vba table values, does anyone know how to write in these cells correct values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with this code so far it prints like this : 
[image: screenshot]
It should calculate the difference from 2 cells the 2nd and 4th if the 2nd is larger and print it in the 2nd row below the original value(as it does on row 78) and then write the value (that is below in the original table) in the 4th column until the 2nd value is "payed off" and then do it with rest of file.
So far my code looks like this:

```
Sub testro()
    Const cSheet As String = "Procenty"
    Const cRange As String = "A2:D71"
    Const cel As Long = 4
    Const cCol As Variant = "A"

    Dim vntS As Variant
    Dim vntT As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    Dim kom As Double, komz As Double, kredyt As Double
    Dim roz As Double, komr As Double, komn As Double
    Dim dz As Date, dw As Date

    vntS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange).Value
    ReDim vntT(1 To 2 * UBound(vntS), 1 To cel)
    kredyt = 0
    r = 1 

    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)
        dz = vntS(i, 1)
        komz = vntS(i, 2)
        dw = vntS(i, 3)
        kom = vntS(i, 4)

        vntT(r, 1) = dz
        vntT(r, 2) = komz
        vntT(r, 3) = dw
        vntT(r, 4) = kom
        r = r + 1

        If komz > kom Then
            komr = komz - kom
            vntT(r, 1) = dz
            vntT(r, 2) = komr
            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = kom
            r = r + 1
        ElseIf komz < kom Then
            komn = kom - komz
            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = komn
            r = r + 1
        ElseIf komz = kom Then
            vntT(r, 1) = dz
            vntT(r, 2) = komz
            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = kom
        End If
    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        emptyRow = .Columns(cCol).Find("*", , xlFormulas, _
                xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row + 1
        'emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(cCol)) + 1
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol).Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol) = kredyt
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: here's how it should look like (it's done manually by me here) [screenshot good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1MEA.png)
EDIT2: here's how it looks before the macro [screenshot before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7q9j.png)
EDIT3:[Screenshot now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLzzy.png)
EDIT4:[changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nerXQ.png) Here's the screenshot after I did what you wrote above: In the row underlined with black color where there is 9.11.2015 and 828 should be 30.11.2015 and 312,11 and this row should be checked with if statements when it's payed off if checks value below and so on

Comment: Well in edit section is example ho it should work, this macro should check the if statements, and for e.g as it is in 1st if it should take values form cells(4th column) and substract 2nd and 4th column until the value from 2nd is completely gone (as shown in screenshot) which I have to do manually now.

Comment: In screenshot good tag there are example data that I do now manually, it's not everything and in screenshot tag it's shon how it's done now. The point in this macro is to do it like on screenshot good and to do it correct according to ifs. If you could download the code and write some random data (1st and 3rd row dates;2nd and 4th numeric values for e.g 230  or 450) and then see how it,s going so far with the code and comapre it with the screenshot good. Entering same data  as in screenshot should be more relevant to my problem.

Comment: 10.09.2015 988 15.09.2015 988
10.10.2015 1140 09.10.2015 1140
13.10.2015 90,98 19.10.2015 100
10.11.2015 1140 09.11.2015 828
11.12.2015 1140 30.11.2015 312,11
07.01.2016 458,46 11.12.2015 828
10.01.2016 1140 14.12.2015 312,11
10.02.2016 1140 10.01.2016 312,11
11.03.2016 1140 12.01.2016 458,46
10.04.2016 1140 12.01.2016 828
13.04.2016 415,9 09.02.2016 828
10.05.2016 1140 24.02.2016 312,11
10.06.2016 1140 09.03.2016 312,11
10.07.2016 1140 09.03.2016 828
14.07.2016 482,02 01.04.2016 312,11

Comment: Now I added how it look before macro and now I think that everything is clear with this, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not sure what this means "and then write the value (that is below in the original table) in the 4th column until the 2nd value is "payed off" " - can you explain more - Just that point

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of difficulty understanding what you were trying to do. Eventually I had to try and replace your variables kom, komz, komr, komn with english names (apologies I'm Irish and English is my only language)

I could be totally wrong but  my guesses were;

```
 komz ... the TotalDebtBefore (the Debt Brought Forward)
 kom .... the amount due or paid now - the installment
 komr ... the RemainingDebt (Carried Forward)
 komn ... An Overpaid Balance
```

With those meanings I could make sense of your code

```
Sub TestRev2()
    Const cSheet As String = "Procenty"
    Const cRange As String = "A2:D71"
    Const cel As Long = 4
    Const cCol As Variant = "A"

    ' My best Guess of variable meanings
    ' DebtBFwd = k o m z - x9
    ' InstallmentAmt = k o m - x10
    ' DebtCFwd = k o m r - x3
    ' OverPaid = k o m n - x3

    Dim vntS As Variant
    Dim vntT As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    Dim kom As Double, komz As Double, kredyt As Double
    Dim roz As Double, komr As Double, komn As Double
    Dim dz As Date, dw As Date

    vntS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange).Value
    ReDim vntT(1 To 2 * UBound(vntS), 1 To cel)
    kredyt = 0
    r = 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)
        dz = vntS(i, 1)
        komz = vntS(i, 2)
        dw = vntS(i, 3)
        kom = vntS(i, 4)

        vntT(r, 1) = dz
        vntT(r, 2) = komz
        vntT(r, 3) = dw
        vntT(r, 4) = kom
        r = r + 1

        If komz > kom Then
            komr = komz - kom
            vntT(r, 1) = dz
            vntT(r, 2) = komr  ' DebtCFwd ?
            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = kom   ' InstallmentAmt ?
            r = r + 1
        End If
        If komz < kom Then
            komn = kom - komz
            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = komn  ' Overpaid Amt ?
            r = r + 1
        End If
        If komz = kom Then
            vntT(r, 1) = dz
            vntT(r, 2) = komz  ' DebtBFwd ?
            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = kom   ' InstallmentAmt ?
            ' Following Line Added
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        emptyRow = .Columns(cCol).Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row + 1
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol).Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol) = kredyt
    End With
End Sub
```

To cut a long story short, you seem to be missing the line

```
            r = r + 1
```

When komz = kom

Whether I'm right or wrong about the meaning of your variables, you need that r = r + 1

Your If, elseif usage was hiding that problem. So I re-arranged them because those  IF's can never overlap

If that is not the only cause of problems, I now have a good grasp of your code

==================================================================
Addendum - After your 3rd Edit

So, IF YOUR LOGIC (in the code) IS CORRECT (and it may not be) the problem lies in this section of code and can only be 1 of 2 lines

```
    If komz > kom Then
        komr = komz - kom
        vntT(r, 1) = dz
        vntT(r, 2) = komr  ' DebtCFwd ?
        vntT(r, 3) = dw
        ' Either the next line is wrong
        vntT(r, 4) = kom   ' InstallmentAmt ?
        r = r + 1
    End If
    If komz < kom Then
        komn = kom - komz
        vntT(r, 3) = dw
        ' Or this next line is wrong
        vntT(r, 4) = komn  ' Overpaid Amt ?
        r = r + 1
    End If
```

I've added the 2 extra comments to show which lines can possibly be causing the 4th column to be incorrect

However, if you explain to me the meaning of the 4 variables, kom, komn, komr and komz I can help resolve the logic - which I suspect may also be wrong

==================================================================
Addendum 2 - Allowing the Code tell you what it is doing

First you need to increase the size of the vntT array by 1 column as follows

```
ReDim vntT(1 To 3 * UBound(vntS), 1 To cel + 1)  ' Added the + 1 at end
```

Then we need to put messages into that extra array column at various places as follows

```
vntT(r, 1) = dz
vntT(r, 2) = komz
vntT(r, 3) = dw
vntT(r, 4) = kom
vntT(r, 5) = " .. A"
r = r + 1

If komz > kom Then
    komr = komz - kom
    vntT(r, 1) = dz
    vntT(r, 2) = komr  ' DebtCFwd ?
    vntT(r, 3) = dw
    vntT(r, 4) = kom   ' InstallmentAmt ?
    vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz > kom"
    r = r + 1
End If
If komz < kom Then
    komn = kom - komz
    vntT(r, 3) = dw
    vntT(r, 4) = komn  ' Overpaid Amt ?
    vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz < kom"
    r = r + 2
End If
If komz = kom Then
    vntT(r, 1) = dz
    vntT(r, 2) = komz  ' DebtBFwd ?
    vntT(r, 3) = dw
    vntT(r, 4) = kom   ' InstallmentAmt ?
    vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz = kom"
    ' Following Line Added
    r = r + 1
End If
```

In the above there are 4 new lines of code each writing data (msgs) into vntT(r,5)
This will help show you where the code is going wrong.

===============================================

## Final Addendum

The following is where the code picks up the source data ... placing it into variables

```
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)
        dz = vntS(i, 1)
        komz = vntS(i, 2)
        dw = vntS(i, 3)
        kom = vntS(i, 4)
```

So, vntS array holds the source data
and vntT array holds the output data - which is wrong for some cases

You may need a new variable to pick up the other date or to calculate a new value, before you put that into the Output array

As I said in comments, I do not know the full business case you are trying to implement, nor do I have the data.

Comment: You see the whole issue is with the data, your code unfortunately odes not fix the problem:(.In EDIT3 I added a screenshot ,on it you can see how it's done now,but it's not good unfortunately.On screenshot in 1 you see that where there is 312 in the same row is 828 from 9.11.2015 while there should be 312,11 from 30.11.2015. I thought about adding variable like "balance" that will check if the debt is payed off(it should look like on screenshot good tag) and when it is next value from 2nd column is checked and so on

Comment: I've added to my answer - at the bottom - to reflect your above comment

Comment: Well komz means obligation to be payed off, kom means payment , komn is overpayment and komr is underpayment

Comment: In the specific case of the 1140 owed, 848 paid with 312 left outstanding, the problem lies with the code when komz>kom.   I'll amend the answer to show you how to track what has been happening

Comment: Ok, answer updated to help you solve the where and why it is going wrong - good luck

Comment: Well I copied your code and it's going wrong with relating the data, the problem I had before and don't know how to solve.Couldn't post screenshot to an edit in question so it's all in my answer below

Comment: Here's what's up after I did what you wrote above: In the row underlined with black color where there is 9.11.2015 and 828 should be 30.11.2015 and 312,11 and this row should be checked with if statements when it's payed off if checks value below and so on

Comment: Ok, so deal with one thing at a time. Figure out where the wrong date came from and where the correct date is ... in the source data ... and then you have to figure out what changes to make in the single line of code that you now know is wrong, then do the same for the wrong value .... where do you get the right value from in the source data

Comment: I know what's wrong but don't know what to do with it, I just don't know how to write it in the sub I've added screenshot how it is but got it deleted because it wasn't in comment or question.... The whole thing is that when the payment(kom) is less than obligation it takes date below and do the komz>kom if

Comment: Ok, there's the real problem. This is a coding forum and you need to be able to do some coding. I do not know the full business case you are trying to implement, nor do I have the data. My aim is to help you progress with your problem. I've gone as far as I can with that. I will make one more amendment to my answer in a few minutes to prompt you further, but you have to do the work thereafter.

Comment: Well the thing you added to the answer is already in the code and I know that it puts data to variables....... As I said before I thought about adding variable like balance that will check if the obligation is payed off but don't know where to put it and that's the biggest problem I think......

Comment: Now I thought about making some kind of recalling the row below but don't know how to do it, when I do this:       If komz > kom Then
    komr = komz - kom
    vntT(r, 1) = dz
    vntT(r, 2) = komr
    vntT(r, 3) = dw
    vntT(r, 4) = kom 
    vntT(r, 5) =   
   
    r = r + 1
     vntT(r, 1) = dz 
    vntT(r, 2) = komr 
    vntT(r, 3) = dw 
    vntT(r, 4) = kom 
 It's still bad, really I have no idea what to do....